# DataGridView storage override

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable where what's stored differs slightly between the two.

For example if cell[0][0] of the DataTable equals 200 then cell[0][0] of the DataGridView equals $2.00.

This works fine but when the operation is switched and data is entered into the cell manually the value isn't stored as I expect.

What I need is to be able to handle a cell change event BEFORE the DataTable cell is updated and override that change. I know I can make the DataGridView virtual and implement the methods myself but I want to avoid that if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution ended up being pretty simple. I handled the ColumnChanging event on the DataTable.